# UTF8 scrambling during c++ file loading

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, wstring

I know loading unicode is a somewhat laboured point, but I can't see how to apply the solutions presented to others to my particular problem.

I have a Win7/C++/DirectX9 GUI library which can render text to the screen. I've never had a problem before since it has only be used with Western European language. Now I have to use it with Hungarian, and it is giving me a headache! My particular problem is with loading the special characters found in that language.

Take this example, FELNŐTTEKNEK, meaning ADULT.

If I hard code this string into my app, it renders correctly:

```
guiTitle->SetText( L"FELNŐTTEKNEK" );
```

This stores the string as a std::wstring, rendering it with ID3DXFont::DrawTextW(). It also proves my chosen font, Futura CE, is able to render the special characters (CE = Central European).

So far so good. Next I simply want to be able to load the text from a text file. No big deal. However the results are bad! The special Ő is replaced by another character, mainly Å or even two characters like Å (2nd one usually unprintable)

I have ensured by input text file is encoded as UTF-8 and am naively trying to load it thus:

```
wifstream f("data/language.ini");
wstring w;  
getline( f, w );    
guiTitle->SetText( w );
```

Somehow I am still scrambling it. Am I loading as UTF-8? Is there a way to ensure this? I just need to ensure I have a wide string with the text as show in text editor.

Any assistance most gratefully received.

Si

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget about `wifstream`, it's just too hard to make it work. Do:

```
ifstream f(L"data/language.ini");
string str;  
getline( f, str );
guiTitle->SetText( utf8_to_utf16(str).c_str() );
```

And use `MultiByteToWideChar` to implement `utf8_to_utf16`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for a speedy response.

Comment: `Forget about wifstream, it's just too hard to make it work` - You mean having to implement an additional function using low level conversion is simpler than imbuing a `wifstream` with the encoding the file is using? I can't follow that argument.

Comment: @Voo: you'll have to implement your own locale on windows, because windows CRT doesn't support a UTF-8 locale (try it).

Answer (score 3):

DrawTextW is expecting UTF-16.

What you're doing is converting each UTF-8 code unit (byte) into a 16 bit value by zero padding it - this correctly converts UTF-8 to UTF-16 only if your UTF-8 exclusively contains characters from the ascii subset of unicode.

What you need to do is to correctly convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16. Load the string into a std::string (not a std::wstring) then convert that UTF-8 string into a UTF-16 string and pass it to the API expecting a UTF-16 string.

Answer (score -1):

Never understood the idea declared [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful) about using UTF-8 everywhere, implementing necessary functions yourself (which you could just as well do for UTF-16 as well) and then converting it back to UTF-16 when communicating with the Windows API (and no idea how that should avoid problems in the Windows API - after all you still give it UTF-16 chars and will therefore hit all the same bugs anyhow), seems quite a lot of extra work for no benefits.

Anyways instead of the "use std::string and then convert it using lowlevel methods to UTF-16" you could just let the API do its job (note this may not result in the best performance, Ray Chen had some series about that way back - though I'd hope newer compilers fixed that and for a normal file that's hardly important).

Basically you can do that:

```
 std::wifstream src;
 src.imbue(std::locale("UTF-8")); // use correct encoding.
 src.open(file);
```

Why do all the work yourself (and every time I don't have to use MultiByteToWideChar I count myself lucky) if the library may do it as well - also makes the intent much clearer.

Comment: it just doesn't work. Try it. Windows doesn't support UTF-8 locale, so you'll have to roll your own (that's what I meant by 'too hard').

Comment: "UTF-16 harmful" thing is about portability and compatibility. If you don't understand, that means that you'd never written portable code. Besides how are you going to return unicode data from `exception::what`?

Comment: My bad I had stuffed that away years ago and had it in a helper library for such a long time I forgot it. Anyways what is your point about not being able to return wstrings from an ascii function? That's the same as saying you can't return a UTF-8 string from a function that expects wstring!